# What is thre reason of core dump?

Tags: c++, coredump, function-try-block

Why do I have core dump in this code
I see output

```
Catch 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  ZERO DIV
Aborted (core dumped)
```

But I expect

```
    Catch 
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
      what():  ZERO DIV
```

**My code**

```
class Q {
public:
    Q(int a, int b) try
    : val(b != 0 ? a / b : throw runtime_error("ZERO DIV"))
    {
        cout << "Q()" << endl;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout << "Catch " << endl;
        val = nullopt;
    }
    ~Q() {
        cout << "~Q()" << endl;
    }
private:
    optional<int> val;
};


int main() {
    Q q = {1, 0};
    return 0;
}
```

I think that the reason of core dump is execution of a / b, but I shouldn't be executed, because b is not zero

Comment: As a side note, what compiler are you using, and do you have warnings enabled? Clang emits _"warning: cannot refer to a non-static member from the handler of a constructor function try block [-Wexceptions]"_ on `val = nullopt;`

Comment: `a / b` is not executed. You are seeing the exception ZERO DIV that you threw

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is simple

Answer (score 4):

The currently handled exception is automatically rethrown if an exception handler in a function-try-block on a constructor doesn't exit via an exception.

That's necessary, because if the constructor has thrown an exception, then it is impossible for the program to continue normally after `Q q = {1, 0};`, since the object `q` can't be properly constructed and usable.

You see the core dump because you don't handle the rethrown exception anywhere in `main`, resulting in a call to `std::terminate`, calling `std::abort` which in turn signals `SIGABRT` which is not handled anywhere, so the OS produces a core dump if configured to do so.

Also, accessing `val` in the exception handler on the constructor would cause undefined behavior. `val`'s lifetime hasn't started since it was never initialized.

You can't use a function-try-block if you still want the construction to succeed. Avoid using exceptions for that at all and if you must, handle the exceptions in normal try-catch blocks.